# Ubuntu 12.04 on PR2 is unable to install libfreenect-dev

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, libfreenect, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on a PR2 robot (hydro) and I would like to install libfreenect-dev to develop a package for rgbd (kinect) mapping. However, I cannot install this library.

I receive the message "E: Package 'libfreenect-dev' has no installation candidate" from the apt-get manager.

I could install it in my workstation (running the same configuration: ubuntu 12.04, ROS hydro) but not in the PR2.

I looked this library into the ros repositories (from the PR2) but I couldn't find it.

Have you experienced this before? Do you have any clue how to install it or why is it not available for the PR2 platform?

I would appreciate your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203008/ubuntu-12.04-on-pr2-is-unable-to-install-libfreenect-dev/) by [Ricardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4272/ricardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-02-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does your sources list have this line:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe

The only way it won't be found is if it can't locate the package, because it is there for precise.

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2015-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0